# Why chrome ignores X-frame-option: sameorigin?

Tags: x-frame-options, clickjacking

Chrome on Mac is ignoring X-frame-options header for my site.

I have set x-frame-options : sameorigin
I am using Google Chrome is up to date
Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Chrome ignores header and opens site in iframe.
Firefox and safari is blocking site to be open in frame.

````
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>i Frame</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>This is clickjacking vulnerable</h3>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/" frameborder="2 px" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>```
````